# What is the method called when i click Next button in New Project Wizard?

Tags: intellij-idea, wizard, intellij-plugin

I am a beginner in `intellij` plugin development. I need to add a project type by my plugin in New Project Wizard. I could manage that part with `<extention>` tags in `plugin.xml`. Now I need to add a `CustomWizardStep` when I click the next button after selecting the project type. What is the first method called when that button is clicked in which class? Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `com.intellij.ui.wizard.WizardStep#onNext` method.
You can extend the `com.intellij.ui.wizard.WizardStep` class to use in your own wizard.